# American English + British English + Xxx English tags Merger/Umbrella Tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We can have specific tags for questions about a specific dialect, but shouldn't there be some form of tag that encompasses anything like this? E.g. `dialects` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but [isn't there one already](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialects)?

Comment: Hmmm.. perhaps it should be added to this question ( http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/bring-vs-take-in-american-english )  (which is what prompted me to ask this question).